# Colorbox First Field Image Style

Tags: 7, views, javascript

Using colorbox in views.

Can someone explain what the functionality of the "Content Image Style for first image" is?

At first glance, I would assume that it allows me to choose an image style for all of my gallery images, and then choose a different image style for the first image, allowing the first image in the gallery to be bigger or smaller, which would be very cool.

However, when I change the image style for the first image and save, all of my images in the gallery are changed to that style.

Am i missing the point here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I have just figured this out.

This only works when you show all multiple fields in the same row.

Changing the field to display all images in the same row, and displaying them in an unordered list sorted it right away.